# Store lat lon in addition to the geography data type?

Tags: postgis

It's my first time using Postgis, I have been doing some reading on using it. I have added a geography data type to my table, but the values are stored in a binary format. Is it good practice to also store the lat and lon in separate columns as text or points??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The coordinates can be computed with [ST_X](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_X.html)/[ST_Y](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Y.html)/[ST_Centroid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Centroid.html), when needed.
If you just want to view the data, use [ST_AsText](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsText.html) or [ST_AsEWKT](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_AsEWKT.html).

You need separate columns only if there is some client software that needs these values, but is not able to use those SQL functions.